# Django: flatpages/default.html not found when usign flatepages

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I completed Django's 7 part tutorial and am now reading both the official documentation about [flat pages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/flatpages/) as well as this other [site](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/04/how-to-use-django-flatpages-app.html).

in

> my_project/settings.py

I have added the `sites` and `flatpages` apps as well as the `SITE_ID`.

in

> my_project/urls.py

I have added

```
urlpatterns += [url(r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),]
```

and because I also need to have `flatpages/default.html` as a template, in

> my_project/templates/flatpages/

there is a file named `default.html`

to make sure it is found back in

> my_projects/settings.py

I updated templates to look like:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So I went onto the admin page and added a `flatpage` named "test" and then went to `...8000:/pages/test/`

to get an error message `TemplateDoesNotExist`.

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Show your view for that url

Comment: @vZ10 there's no view I guess, since its a flat page.
SumNeuron, can you share what your Templates = [..] looks like in settings.py?

Comment: @Anupam I have included it

Comment: You haven't shown the full traceback -- it can be useful because it shows the list of directories that Django searched for the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for your current `DIRS` in your `TEMPLATES` setting to work, make sure that your `templates/flatpages/` directory is in your outer `my_project` directory (the one that contains `manage.py`), not the inner directory (the one that contains `settings.py`).